# how to convert datetime.date to string without knowing the exact date

Tags: python

I have a variable:

```
somedate
```

it can be `04.05.2015`, `04.05`, or `2015`.

how can I convert this variable to string?

Comment: What would you like the output string to be?

Comment: Whats the type of `04.05.2015`?

Comment: Your variables already look like strings. Are you asking how to parse them? Or how to normalize them into a common format? Your question is not very clear.

Answer (score 2):

I've just tried this...

```
>>> x = datetime.date(2015, 10, 2)
>>> x
datetime.date(2015, 10, 2)
>>> print x
2015-10-02
>>> str(x)
'2015-10-02'
```

I guess `str()` does what you want.